# How can two IIS7 domains share SSL port 443 on one IP?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate, port-443

I have two domains: domain1.com and domain2.com. I also have two GoDaddy SSL certificates (one cert for each domain). I only have one IP. I'm running IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 standalone server in a workgroup, not a domain.

How can I bind each certificate to appropriate domain?

Answer (score 5):

In IIS 7, you can only have two SSL-enabled sites on the same listening port if they're using the same certificate - this would need to be a wildcard or subject alternate name certificate which covers all of the names.

Since your sites don't share a domain, look into getting a SAN cert (some vendors, including GoDaddy, call it a "UCC" cert for some reason), or more IP addresses for your existing certs.

Answer (score 1):

In the binding for 443/SSL in the site config, look for the tick box to use Server Name Identification (SNI)

SNI support enables multiple SSL bindings on single IP addresses.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability